# Enable and disable syntax highlighting in Atom editor - How?

Tags: syntax-highlighting, atom-editor

How do I enable and disable the different syntax highlighting in the Atom editor? There seems to be syntax highlighting enabled, by default, for plain text files. I want most of this disabled.

Comment: Do these files end with .txt?

Comment: @jmh yes these are *.txt files